# Replacing anchor tag text after it is clicked without removing css

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am changing anchor tag text once it is clicked using jquery (`replaceWith`) and it is working fine. But it also replaces the css of the anchor tag text.

Can anyone help me how not to replace css or add it again.

My html is as follows:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12" >
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success deal" target="_blank" style="width:100%;background:#b71c1c;" rel="nofollow, noindex" 
       href="<?= $coin["link"]; ?>" >
        <b>Get Offer</b>
    </a>
</div>
```

and code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.deal').click(function(){
       $(this).replaceWith("<?php echo $coin['coupon_code']; ?>");
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please edit as your a tag is not visible in question.

Comment: Is `$coin['coupon_code']` HTML or plain text? If it's plain text, then you are completely replacing the anchor. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to replace the content of the inner `<b>` tag, this is your best option:

```
$('.deal').click(function(){
   $(this).find('b').text('<?php echo $coin['coupon_code']; ?>');
});
```

Comment: But if I want to add css how can it be possible

Comment: To the `<b>`: `$(this).find('b').css("propertyname","value");` To the `<a>`: `$(this).css("propertyname","value");`  If lots of css has to change, consider making a new class and using `.addClass()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If `<?php echo $coin['coupon_code']; ?>` contains `html` tags use

```
$(this).find('b').html('<?php echo $coin['coupon_code']; ?>');
```

Or if it is plain text use

```
$(this).find('b').text('<?php echo $coin['coupon_code']; ?>');
```

If you don't want bold remove `.find('b')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you just need to change text.

```
 $(this).html("<?php echo '<b>'.$coin['coupon_code'].'</b>'; ?>");
```

Comment: That will also replace the `<b>` tag.

Comment: But how can I add css using Jquery in it.